# How to add cssclass to a single text string in code behind in C# VS 2010?

Tags: c#, css, string, code-behind

I have a gridview in the aspx file. In the aspx.cs file I have 2 string variables which I want to display as one string in one cell in the gridview, thats no problem. The problem is that I want to have a smaller fontsize on one of the two string variables and I have to do that in the aspx.cs file, I cannot do that on the gridview because I have 2 string variables which I will display as one in one cell in the gridview.

Comment: What do you mean by 'add a cssclass to a single text string' ?

Comment: OK I will try again, sorry!  I have a gridview in the aspx file.  In the aspx.cs file I have 2 string variables which I want to display as one string in one cell in the gridview, thats no problem. The problem is that I want to have a smaller fontsize on one of the two string variables and I have to do that in the codebehind file, I cannot do that on the gridview because I have 2 string variables which I will display in one cell in the gridview.

Answer (score 2):

Make it as a label and refer to the label in you CSS file

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Use the ID to refer to that specific label.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with simple HTML, no C# required.

In your markup, Add a `span` tag around the text and assign a class to this:

```
<span class="myText">Lorem Ipsum</span>

.myText
{
   color:red;
}
```

If you need to do this with code behind, you can use a `Label`:

```
<asp:Label id="lbl" runat="server">Lorem Ipsum</asp:Label>
```

Then you can add a `CssClass` in your code behind:

```
lbl.CssClass = "myText";
```